# I am getting data from the server and displaying into spinner .but when i select the item it does not displaying on the toolbar

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-volley, toolbar

This is my `onActivityCreated()` method:

```
     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           setHasOptionsMenu(true)
           super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        }
```

This is my `onCreateOptionMenu()` method where i added the `spinner` to the `toolbar`:

```
 @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner).setVisible(true);
            mCountrySpinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);


            ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mCountryList);
            countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
            countryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();            

    }


My menu.xml :

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:title="@string/countryname"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    app:showAsAction="always"

    ></item>


</menu>
```

Comment: What does not display in the toolbar ? The spinner or the data in the spinner.Can you please explain more and how did you get `mCountryList`

Comment: data showing  in the spinner but when i select the particular item in the spinner  it is not displaying in the toolbar.please tell me what can i do ??

Comment: Can you post you `menu.xml` file

Comment: what happened soham.please help me.if you have any sloution regarding this.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/how-to-add-spinner-dropdown-list-to-android-actionbar-toolbar.html)

Comment: i solved my problem.by calling the mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged() method where i am parsing the json data.btw thanks.